# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, using triggers

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a trigger to add in SQL Server database table, first everything is ok but after I detect that I can't add data into my table, then this message appears :

> SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

If you've any idea to solve this problem please help me;

My salutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have something like this:

```
SELECT  foo
FROM    Bar
WHERE   baz = (
        SELECT  baz
        FROM    Whatsit
        WHERE   a = 42
);
```

The bit in `()` is the subquery. You can't do that when the subquery returns more than one row, because then SQL Server has no idea which row's value to use in the comparison.

The solution is to either:

1. Modify the subquery so it only returns a single row, or
2. Modify the overall statement to use joins

Which you use depends on the specific query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using = or !=, instead you can use IN or NOT IN. You can also using EXISTS or NOT EXISTS depending on what you are trying to do.